# can't read route parameter in angular

Tags: flutter

i'm trying to retrieve item data by id in angular 14, I tried adding the id to the route (:id), and then created the service method and tried to implement it in the component ts page. Whenever I add the (:id) to the route in the routing page, I get the following error:

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext')`

**this is my routing page:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'missions-list',
        component: ListMissionsComponent,
        data: { title: 'Missions' },
      },
      {
        path: 'mission-details/:id',
        component: MissionDetailsComponent,
        data: { title: 'Détails du mission' },
      },
      {
        path: 'add-mission',
        component: AddMissionComponent,
        data: { title: 'Ajouter une mission' },
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

**and this is my service method:**

```
 getById(id: number): Observable<Mission> {
    return this.http.get(`${baseUrl}/${id}`);
    
  }
```

**and finally my ts page:**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getMissionById(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id']);
  }


  getMissionById(id: any): void {
    this.missionService.getById(id)
      .subscribe({
        next: (data) => {
          this.mission = data;
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: (e) => console.error(e)
      });
  }
```

can anyone help me out in solving this error? I'd appreciate it a lot!

I tried the service method without passing the id in the route, just by setting 1 as an input for the method and it works pretty fine!